# C application skips my scanf calls

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to write code to count how many times a string repeats inside another one. (If there is some easier approach, please let me know.)

Here is the code that I have now:

```
int getStringLenght (char str[]) {
    int lenghtOfTheString;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if(str[i] == '\0') {
            lenghtOfTheString = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return lenghtOfTheString;
}
int main()
{
    printf("Type a string: ");
    char T[1024];
    scanf("%s",&T);
    char P[100];
    printf("Type a substring: ");
    scanf("%s",&P);
    printf("%s",P);
    int stringSize = getStringLenght (P);
    int occurences = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int j;

        if(T[i] == P[0]) {
            for (j = 0;j<10;j++) {
                char c1 = T[i+j];
                char c2 = P[j];
                if(c1 != c2) {

                    break;
                }
                if(j == stringSize-1) {
                    occurences++;
                    //printf("string iguais em i = %d",i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe substring %s was found %d times", P, occurences);

    return 0;
}
```

The app compiles. When I type "banana", for example, on the first `scanf`, and then "na" on the second, the app comes out with the right answer. *But*, if I type "banana and milk" on the first `scanf`, it automatically interprets the second `scanf` as "and", even when I don't type anything but "banana and milk <kbd>ENTER</kbd>"

What's happening?

Comment: Try `sscanf` instead of `scanf` in your code.

Answer (score 4):

`scanf`'s "%s" conversion only reads characters until it encounters white-space (e.g., space, new-line, or tab). When you enter more than one word, it reads the first. The second call reads the second, and so on.

If you want to read an entire line, you usually want to use `fgets` instead (`scanf` can do the job as well, but it's a little trickier, and uses a feature of which many are unaware, so they often find it difficult to understand).

Comment: Wait, scanf can be made to not stop on whitespace? Pray tell!

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Yes. `char your_string[256]; scanf("%255[^\n]%c", your_string, &some_char);` Note that (to avoid being essentially identical to `gets`) you need to supply the size. Also note that the size you supply needs to be one less than the size of the array. As I've done it here, the `some_char` will normally hold a new-line, but the line was longer than you allowed for, it'll be the next character.

Comment: fgets does work, but now my string contains a newline inside it. is there some way to remove it?

Comment: @Lucas: Several. One easy (but unconventional) one is: `strtok(your_string, "\n");`. A bit more work, but more conventional, is `char *pos = strchr(string, '\n'); if (pos!=NULL) *pos = '\0';`

Answer (score 1):

You don't understand how scanf works. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/ `%s` will only read one string, terminated by white space. If you want to keep reading strings, or read a line, you have to keep using scanf until one of your strings ends in a new line or EOF, or use another function, like `fgets`.

Comment: `cplusplus.com` can't seem to get anything quite right (in this case, their description doesn't even mention scanset conversions).

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that many functions are already implemented. This is why your `getStringLength` (you have typo in it's name) is  needless. You can simply check the string's length using `strlen` function from `string.h`. What is more when you import this file you also have access to `strstr` function which finds the first occurrence of a given substring in a string. Try to use them instead of reinventing the wheel ;)

Comment: All good advice, but should probably be a comment, as it does nothing to (even try to) answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

That is a standart problem with `scanf`. There are 3 ways to fix this:

---

### 1: Call fflush after each scanf:

```
scanf("%s", some_string); // you don't need to write &some_string because giving a array to a function automatically converts it to a pointer
fflush(stdin);
```

`fflush()` isn't available on every system.

---

### 2: Putting scanf in a loop:

```
do
    scanf("%s", somestring);
while (getchar() != '\n');
```

---

### 3: Don't use scanf! Use fgets and sscanf!

```
char buffer[100]; // buffer for fgets()
fgets(buffer, 100, stdin); // read a line from stdin (standart input) into buffer
sscanf(buffer, "%s", some_string); // convert buffer in any format you want
```